vscode.DiagnosticCollection doesn't show all its items in Problems panel
I'm developing VSCode extension for 4gl programming language.
My problem is: VSCode Problems panel shows only errors/warns of the last task, discarding previous ones.
For example, I compile file1, getting its errors in Problems tab. Then I compile file2.
I see now that errors of the file1 are gone and Problems panel contains only errors of the file2.
Trying to solve this, I started using DiagnosticCollection instead of task problemMatchers.
The flow now is as follows:

VSCode task starts compilation, getting output into terminal (vscode.Pseudoterminal to be precise);
Output is parsed by RegExps, just like by problemMatchers;
Once error found, vscode.Diagnostic entry is created and added to the global DiagnosticCollection;

Everything is good until now - all errors contained in DiagnosticCollection are shown in Problems panel.
Then I compile another file, adding its errors to the same DiagnosticCollection, so finally it contains Diagnostic for both compiled files.
But VSCode Problems panel still shows error of the last compiled file, disregarding other entries in DiagnosticCollection.
Is there a way to force VSCode to show all entries from DiagnosticCollection?
Or even more wide question - how to persist errors/warns between tasks and show all of them in Problems panel?
